# Django import error when trying to import a model from a different app

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror

I've gone through just about every Python/Django import StackOverflow question and I still can't fix this issue. In Django I am trying to create a new model that has a foreign key of a model in a different app. I don't appear to be able to import this.

I am running Python 3.8 on Windows 10, running within a clean virtual environment

Steps:

```
> pip install django
> django-admin startproject django1
> cd django1
> python manage.py startapp app1
> python manage.py startapp app2
```

Add both apps to the INSTALLED_APPS in django1/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
    'app2'
]
```

Create a model in app1/models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class App1Model1(models.Model):
    val1 = models.BooleanField()
    val2 = models.BooleanField()
```

Create a model in app2/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from ..app1.models import App1Model1


class App2Model1(models.Model):
    ref1 = models.ForeignKey(App1Model1, on_delete=model.CASCASE)
```

Pycharm is fine with the relative import, but as soon as I run manage.py I get:

```
django1>python manage.py runserver
...
File "C:\DEV\sherpytest\django1\app2\models.py", line 2, in <module>
from ..app1.models import App1Model1
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

If I change the import in app2\models.py to this:

```
from django.db import models
from django1.app1.models import App1Model1


class App2Model1(models.Model):
    ref1 = models.ForeignKey(App1Model1, on_delete=model.CASCASE)
```

I get:

```
django1>python manage.py runserver
...
File "C:\DEV\sherpytest\django1\app2\models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django1.app1.models import App1Model1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django1.app1'
```

I have tried creating a setup.py in django1 and installing it to turn it into a package (even though no tutorial tells me to do that) and still having issue.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you share the directory tree/structure?

Comment: @KaranKumar, added!

Comment: from app1.models import App1Model1 << Just use this

Comment: @KarenKumar, AKX got in before you below with the same fix, but this did fix my problem, thank you for your answer!

Comment: That's good to know. Keep grinding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the structure is

```
- project root
  - manage.py
  - django1 (project)
  - app1 (app)
  - app2 (app)
```

you always import things with `app1.models`, `app2.models`, `django1.somethingsomething`, never with a relative import that'd go up to the "root" level where `manage.py` tends to live. (Naturally, if you have packages within your apps, you're free to use relative imports within them, but not across apps.)

That is,

```
from django.db import models
from app1.models import App1Model1

class App2Model1(models.Model):
    ref1 = models.ForeignKey(App1Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can also refer to other apps' models by strings, to avoid some circular import issues:

```
from django.db import models

class App2Model1(models.Model):
    ref1 = models.ForeignKey("app1.App1Model1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: That was it, you're a lifesaver, thank you so much! I never thought to try that because Pycharm didn't recognise it as an import. *face palm *